# Ms Access and Vb .net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

how do i get the values from my database in access in vb
i have a table named Rates that has column PerMinute and column Amount

i want to access the data in the amount column. and make it appear on the AmountToPay.text please help me im new with database.

Comment: Did you search the internet for e.g. "access vb.net database"?

Comment: Also, you might want to avoid Access, and move on to some real DBMS which is ACID http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim conStringBuilder = New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder
        With conStringBuilder
            ' Path to your access db
            .DataSource = "c:\db.accdb"

            ' For .mdb files change provider to Jet
            ' .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
            .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        End With

        Dim con As New OleDbConnection(conStringBuilder.ConnectionString)

        Dim cmdString = "SELECT * FROM Rates"
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(cmdString, con)

        Dim dTable As New DataTable
        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dTable.Load(dReader)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

        ' Output to console.
        ' You may want to set AmountToPay.text here
        For Each dRow In dTable.Rows
            Console.WriteLine(dRow("PerMinute"))
            Console.WriteLine(dRow("Amount"))
            Console.WriteLine()
        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable Ken. Answer adapted.

Comment: Much better. :) I'll remove my comment about the first answer you posted.

Comment: wow thanks for the help. the code helped me alot. i'll be using this as my reference for future coding.